# Кодировка для ajax

Tags: ajax, кодировка

Как правильно менять кодировку, когда используется ajax? У меня вместо русских букв вопросы выходят. У меня кодировка windows-1251.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть доступ к странице, куда идёт запрос, то само-собой меняйте кодировку прямо там.

А вообще, лучше установите на везде UTF-8.

Comment: Я не помню точно, UTF-8 понимает русский язык?

Comment: Простите, вы хотите сказать, что UTF-8 не работает с русским языком?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
Может что-то неправильно делаю, но у меня вопросы �.

Comment: Кодировку самого файла установите как UTF-8.